"Invalid Qualifier" VBA IF THEN multiple criteria nested loop
This may be beyond my skill set at the moment, but I'm attempting to create a nested loop referencing 2 active worksheets. It is grabbing 2 specific values from one sheet1 if sheet2 meets multiple criteria in sheet1.
The sheets are ProjSheet (project sheet) and PlateSheet (Plates within projects). I need project info (specifically batch and farm) to get pulled in from the ProjSheet to the PlateSheet, IF the project codes match AND the plate code is <= the first plate# in ProjSheet AND >= the last plate code in ProjSheet. Should just be a row-by-row IF AND AND THEN nested loop.
Again, I may not have the knowledge or skills yet to realize what I'm doing wrong or how to structure this properly.
Sub ProjectPlateLoops()

'define workbooks and worksheets
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim PlateSheet As Worksheet
Dim ProjSheet As Worksheet

' HOPE THIS ACTIVATES EACH SHEET AS IT IS USED IN LOOP?
Set ws = ActiveSheet
PlateSheet = ws("Plate_Analysis")
ProjSheet = ws("Project_Alalysis")

'last row in Project Analysis Page
Dim lrProject As Long
lrProj = ProjSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
'law row in Plate Analysis Page
Dim lrPlate As Long
lrPlate = PlateSheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

' Create Loop; if 3 conditions are met, print Batch and Farm from Project sheet to Plate sheet
Dim i, j As Long
For i = 3 To lrProj
Dim FarmProj, BatchProj, ProjCodeProj As Object
Dim FirstPlateProj, LastPlateProj As Integer
FarmProj = ProjSheet.Range("D3" & i)
BatchProj = ProjSheet.Range("E3" & i)
ProjCodeProj = ProjSheet.Range("F3" & i)
FirstPlateProj = ProjSheet.Range("J3" & i)
LastPlateProj = ProjSheet.Range("L3" & i)
  For j = 3 To lrPlate
  Dim FarmPlate, BatchPlate, ProjCodePlate As Object
  Dim PlateNumPlate As Integer
  FarmPlate = PlateSheet.Range("H3" & j)
  BatchPlate = PlateSheet.Range("G3" & j)
  ProjCodePlate = PlateSheet.Range("F3" & j)
  PlateNumPlate = PlateSheet.Range("E3" & j)
    If ProjCodeProj.Value = ProjCodePlate.Value And _
      PlateNumPlate.Value >= FirstPlateProj.Value And _
      PlateNumPlate.Value <= LastPlateProj.Value Then
        BatchPlate.Cells.Value = BatchProj.Cells.Value
        FarmPlate.Cells.Value = BatchProj.Cells.Value
    End If
  Debug.Print (i)
  Debug.Print (j)
  End If
  Next j
Next i

End Sub

The problem I'm running into is with the Object in the second criteria:
      PlateNumPlate.Value >= FirstPlateProj.Value And _

PlateNumPlate is giving me a "Invalid Qualifier" error and I'm not sure why or what to do about it in this instance. Changing the object type to Object instead of String cleared up another issue but created this.
I'd be very grateful for any assistance!

ProjSheet.Range("D3" & i) do you mean ProjSheet.Range("D" & i)  ?

PlateNumPlate is an integer. You can't use PlateNumPlate.Value.  Try PlateNumPlate>= FirstPlateProj

Dim FirstPlateProj, LastPlateProj As Integer - FirstPlateProj is defined as Variant instead of Integer. The code should be Dim FirstPlateProj As Integer, LastPlateProj As Integer

PlateSheet = ws("Plate_Analysis") should be (eg) Set PlateSheet = wb.Worksheets("Plate_Analysis") (after setting wb to the appropriate workbook)

I would skip most of those range-type variables and just work directly with the cells:
Sub ProjectPlateLoops()

    'define workbooks and worksheets
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, PlateSheet As Worksheet, ProjSheet As Worksheet
    Dim pltNum As Long, lrProj As Long, lrPlate As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim proj
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or ActiveWorkbook?
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set PlateSheet = wb.Worksheets("Plate_Analysis")
    Set ProjSheet = wb.Worksheets("Project_Alalysis")
    
    'last rows in Project Analysis/Plate sheets (call separate function for this)
    lrProj = LastOccupiedRow(ProjSheet)
    lrPlate = LastOccupiedRow(PlateSheet)
    
    ' Create Loop; if 3 conditions are met, print Batch and Farm from Project sheet to Plate sheet
    For i = 3 To lrProj
        proj = ProjSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value
        For j = 3 To lrPlate
            If PlateSheet.Cells(j, "F").Value = proj Then
                pltNum = PlateSheet.Cells(j, "E").Value
                If pltNum >= ProjSheet.Cells(i, "J").Value And pltNum <= ProjSheet.Cells(i, "L").Value Then
                    PlateSheet.Cells(j, "G").Value = ProjSheet.Cells(i, "E").Value 'batch
                    PlateSheet.Cells(j, "H").Value = ProjSheet.Cells(i, "E").Value 'E again?
                End If
           End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

Function LastOccupiedRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedRow = f.Row
End Function

This could be improved on by declaring some constants to represent the column positions on each sheet.  Eg:
Const COL_PROJ_PROJID As String = "D" 'Project column on Project sheet

Const COL_PLT_PLTNUM As String = "E"  'Plate column on Plate sheet

Then you could refer to
proj = ProjSheet.Cells(i, COL_PROJ_PROJID).Value
...which makes your code easier to read

Thank you so much for your response! I'll continue working on this. I have a feeling I may have to re-structure the 2 tables I'm looping through so it's not so convoluted.
